# How to manipulate a JSONArray in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

i have a php function which returns me this code in JSON

```
{"0":{"title":"Dans l\u2019appartement"},"1":{"title":"A l\u2019a\u00e9roport - D\u00e9part de B\u00e9atrice"},"2":{"title":"Visite chez Jean-Louis"},"3":{"title":"Anita \u00e0 la matenit\u00e9"},"4":{"title":"Visite chez Jean-Louis 2"},"5":{"title":"H\u00e9l\u00e9na pr\u00e9sent\u00e9e \u00e0 la famille"},"6":{"title":"Chez des proches"},"7":{"title":"Soir\u00e9e souvenir avec un proche - Photos, histoires"},"8":{"title":"Douceline tenant un b\u00e9b\u00e9"},"9":{"title":"Visite chez Jean-Louis 3"},"10":{"title":"Bapt\u00eame de Alexandra - Dans l\u2019\u00e9glise"}}
```

and i want to manipulated in JQuery I’ve did this but it doesn’t work

```
$.each(json, function(item, value) {
            console.log(value);
                $.each(value, function() {
                   console.log(this.title);
                });
            });
```

any ideas thanks a lot

Comment: assuming that blob has the variable name "json" couldn't you just do this
`
for(var key in json){
  console.log(key + ' title: ' + json[key].title);
};`

Comment: if you sent data as array of objects it simplifies things a bit `[{"title":"..."},{"title":"..."}]`

Answer (score 1):

The first traversal using each provides you the **object** containing the value of **title** field.

So , Simply fetch the value using :

```
$.each(json, function(item, value) {
     alert(value.title);        
 });
```

### And here is the [demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzbCM/2/)

Comment: i've done wath you have told me it's show me this error ` Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '986' in #<error>`

Comment: You get the value of json from AJAx call ... if yes make sure that you use dataType : 'json' .... or you could parse the JSON data first using var json = $.parseJSON(data);

Comment: it's working now after i've added the parse line, but in my php function that i call in ajax i've write echo json_encode($test) it's not enough ?

Comment: That is a must in server side (to send JSON) ... but the client side script need to know that which format/type of data is being received. And hence the necessity of parsing.  .... (And if you are using AJAX i recommend you to use `dataType : 'json'` instead)